# Find $\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{x}{\arcsin x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$.

Tags: limits

Find $\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\dfrac{x}{\arcsin x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$.

$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=e^a$ with $a=\lim_{X\to 0}\dfrac{1}{x^2}\left(\dfrac{x}{\arcsin x}-1\right)=\lim_{X\to 0}\dfrac{x-\arcsin x}{x^3}$

Continue i used formular L'hospotal .

Comment: My answer is $e^{-\frac{1}{6}}$

Comment: Better to show your work, not your answer...

Comment: Perhaps the change of variable $x=\sin t$ will prove helpful before going on to apply L'Hopital.

Answer (score 1):

My hint:

Put $$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x}{\arcsin x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}=\exp\left\{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}\ln\frac{x}{\arcsin x}\right\}=\exp\left\{-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}\ln\frac{\arcsin x}{x}\right\}$$

We use Taylor' expansion, we get:

$$\arcsin x=x+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)\to \frac{\arcsin x}{x}=1+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)$$

Hence:

$$L=\exp\left\{-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)\right)\right\}=\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{6}\right\}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{e}}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. For sure, you could continue using L'Hospital but you can do it faster if you are allowe to use Taylor expansions.
Developed at x=0, ArcSin(x) is given by x + x^3/6 + (3 x^5)/40; I am sure you can finish from here and confirm your answer.